# Evaluate a class binding to string?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

If I bind a class:

```
:class="['string-class', {'test-case-class': true}]
```

It will add both of the classes above, but how can I evaluate the above to a string form. I need to do this as a third party component I am using only accepts strings for a class property.

Edit

I want the above to be able to output: `'string-class test-case-class'` just as you would see on a component that :class would be on.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by evaluate to string form?

Comment: I have edited the original question.

Comment: You need to be more specific about how the component is used, and how it's constructed. It appears you are trying to reproduce `Vue`'s compiling process.

Comment: Are you saying you have a component / element where you have bound a `class` attribute with Vue, and you want to know how to then get the value of that as a string?

Comment: Yes thanksd - almost, I have the above passed in as a prop, I need to evaluate it to a string for a 3rd party component.

Comment: @panthro i think you should use mixins or get data properties keys and values

Comment: Can you bind the class to a function that returns a string, rather than to literals?  That should give you the string anywhere you can access the function.

Comment: Joe Z - could you post an example please?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind the class to a function, rather than literals.  For instance:

```
:class="getClasses"
```

where the function is computed:

```
computed: {
    getClasses: function() {
        return 'string-class test-case-class'
    },
```

You can then use it just like any other computed function:

```
{{ getClasses }}
```

Should show the string literal 'string-class test-case-class'.

Comment: This won't compute this though: ['string-class', {'test-case-class': true}]

Comment: You _could_ have the classes as data items, and have two functions: one that returns the literal without the array and object decorations, and one that returns it with them.  However, it seems likely that this would scale somewhat poorly if you have many classes with lots of decisions to make.